# How to print a page with dynamic content with borders without it breaking?

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

The content inside the `ol` tag will be dynamic in length (entered by user). Is there any way to print with borders in each page for this scenario? I can't use JS as the current module I'm working on is converting pure html to pdf.

[Currently, the border works for the first page only since I put a static height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ts1.png)

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #999; margin-top:11px; height:270mm;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; word-break: break-word;">
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:bottom;height:20px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:bottom;height:50px; text-align:justify">
         <ol style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">LONG CONTENT HERE</ol>
     </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). It has great features.